# How to Configure the Scroll View?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, storyboard

I am currently creating an app that utilizes a scroll view to create an onboarding experience for the app. There are supposed to be 7 slides and every time you scroll or click a button it should go to the next slide. However, the issue is that it goes to the last slide as soon as you run the program. You can see my code below:

```
//
//  WelcomeViewController.swift
//  Student Central v2
//
//  Created by Varshith Peddi on 2/21/23.
//

import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var holderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var description1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var skipButton: UIButton!
    
    /*
    private let pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let pageControl = UIPageControl()
        pageControl.numberOfPages = 7
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
        return pageControl
    }()
*/
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        //pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        //view.addSubview(pageControl)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        configure()
    }
    /*
    @objc private func pageControlDidChange(_ sender: UIPageControl){
        let current = sender.currentPage
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(current) * view.frame.size.width, y: 0), animated: true)
        
    }
    */
     
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 720, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 70)
        
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        // set up scrollview
        
        let titles = ["Welcome", "Maps", "Schedule", "Contact", "Quick Links", "Student Help", "Calendar"]
        
        let taglines = ["CHS Student Central will be a centralized app for all students. The\n app contains almost everything someone could wish for as a student at \nCoppell High School.", "Access both the map layout of the school inside and the map layout\n of things outside the school such as the football field, parking lot, and\n much more.", "View both your class schedule and shuttle schedule (if applicable).", "Use this section as an easy way to contact your teachers, counselors, \nand admins of Coppell High School", "This section of the app has all the frequently visited sites that students tend\n to use. It is a quick and easy way to access websites such as HAC, Clever,\n KCBY, Sidekick, and many more", "Use this section of the app if you or another student is in distress. You can\n request basic humanitarian aid such as food, shelter, or medical help. You \ncan also request services such as family support, and a lot of counseling.", "Use this to view the daily Coppell High School Calendar."]
        
        for x in 0..<7 {
            
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 36)
            label.text = titles[x]
            
            description1.textAlignment = .center
            description1.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
            description1.text = taglines[x]
            description1.numberOfLines = 3
            
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            
            if (x == 0){
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Onboarding_1")
            } else if (x == 1){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "map.fill")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            } else if (x == 2){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait.fill")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            } else if (x == 3){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            } else if (x == 4){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "safari.fill")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            } else if (x == 5){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "cross.circle.fill")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            } else if (x == 6){
                imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar")
                let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(paletteColors: [UIColor(red: 176/255.0, green: 3/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
                imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
            }
            
            button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .black
            button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
            if (x == 6){
                button.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
            }
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.tag = x + 1

            skipButton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
            skipButton.setTitle("Skip", for: .normal)
            skipButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 30)
            
            skipButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            skipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton2(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func didTapButton(_ button:UIButton) {
        
        guard button.tag < 7 else{
            //dismiss
            //Core.shared.setIsNotNewUser()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        //scroll to next page
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: holderView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(button.tag), y: 0), animated: true)
    }

    @objc func didTapButton2(_ button:UIButton) {
        //dismiss
        //Core.shared.setIsNotNewUser()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension WelcomeViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //pageControl.currentPage = Int(floorf(Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Float(scrollView.frame.size.width)))
    }
 
}
```

I used a storyboard and this is how my screen looks:

[image]

Comment: Set the scroll view's content offset to 0 at the end of `configure`?

Comment: It looks like you're just looping over your data and setting your views outlets to be the last items, that why you're seeing the last page. Do you see your scrollview scroll to the last page when you run the app?

Comment: If this is the case I advise switching from a scrollView to a vertical collectionView with paging enabled. This will force you down the correct path with your views and data.

Comment: @OneCommentMan yes I see the last page when I run the app. I am unable to see the pages before.

Comment: I think you’re a bit confused. You only have one set of outlets, it doesn’t matter how many times you loop over the data and set the outlets values, its just going to replace the displayed data NOT create new ones. This is why I suggested a UICollectionView, this will force you down the right path in UI and Data.

A quick search and I found this, its what you want only horizontal, easy to switch to vertical. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs7sl_WaL1E

Comment: @VarshithPeddi - if your "slides" are going to be complex / interactive, this is what a `UIPageViewController` is designed for. If the "slides" are simple / non-interactive, use a `UIStackView` to hold the slides and add the stack view to the scroll view.